# Probability intersection

Tags: probability

If P(A)=0,5, P(A∩B)=0,2 and P(A∪B)=0,9, find P(B)?

I was able to find P(B),being it 0.6.
But them I tried to calculate the P(A∩B) to see if it would match the value given,and it didn't am I using the wrong formula?or is it something missing on the question?Shouldn't the question give if it's conditional probability or dependent events.

The formula I used was P(A)*P(B).

Thanks

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ equals $P(A)P(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are _known_ to be independent events, e.g. because the problem states so explicitly, or there is information in the problem statement that allows you to _infer_ that $A$ and $B$ are independent events, or there is some other information that makes it _reasonable_ to assume that the events are independent though some may question this. As an example of this last case, two successive tosses of a coin may be deemed to be dependent by the paranoid who worries that some atoms got knocked off when the coin banged on the table the first time.

Comment: In _your_ question, there is _nothing_ to indicate that $A$ and $B$ can be considered to be independent events, and so calculation of $P(A\cap B)$ as $P(A)P(B)$ is not valid. Indeed, since $P(A\cap B)$ _can_ be calculated explicitly from the given information, and it happens to _not be equal to_ $P(A)P(B)$, you have, in fact, proved a result that is not asked for in your problem: $A$ and $B$ are _dependent_ events.

Comment: As I tought so since the exercise didn't gave if it's independent events i can't see if it matches,tough it wasn't necessary for the exercise to give you this as you could reach it without knowing if it's independent or not.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes,I was just trying to see if the value matched and confirm it was correct.So I would need to use P(A) · P(B|A) or maybe even another approach?

Comment: You are missing the point entirely. You do not **need** to calculate $P(A\cap B)$ as anything -- not as $P(A)P(B)$ nor as $P(A)P(B\mid A)$ nor $1 - P(A^c\cup B^c)$ etc: you are **told** that the value of $P(A\cap B)$ and are asked to **find** $P(B)$. Once you have done that, you can rest on your laurels; **nothing more is needed.**  But, if you _do_ want to do something more, _now_ that you know $P(B)$, you can _compute_ $P(A)P(B)$, note that it does not equal $P(A\cap B)$ which you know already, and add a corollary: "$A$ and $B$ are _dependent_ events. You could also....

Comment: You could also calculate $P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(A\cap B}{P(A)}$ (note that both the numerator and denominator of the fraction are _given_ to you -- all that is needed is to divide one by the other -- and have a piece of information that you did not know explicitly. Since $P(B\mid A) \neq P(B)$, you have _another_ way of showing that $A$ and $B$ are _not independent_ events.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yup that's it,thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain your result easily knowing that $P(A∪B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B)$. As you said, you must obtain $P(B)=0.6$. Of course you don't obtain $P(A∩B) = P(A) P(B)$: this result is true if and only if the events A and B are independent.

Answer (score 0):

The probability we have $A$ and not $B$ is $P(A)-P(A\cap B)=0.3$ . on the other hand $P(A\cup B)$ is $P(A-B)+P(B)$ (since they are exclusive events), so $0.9=0.3+x$, so $x=0.6$ as desired.

Comment: Yes I was able to find this.Them I tried to see if the value matched using the intersection to see if it was correct.The formula I used was P(A)*P(B),not giving 0.2 as it was given on the exercise.